# Count certain values of column in group id

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to count the number of `A's` within-group id.

```r
df<- data.frame( id= c(1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 3, 3, 3,3 ,3,3,4,4,4, 5,5,6,6), value= c(NA, NA,"A", "A", NA,NA,"A","A","B","A",NA,NA,"B","A","B","A", NA, NA,"B",NA, NA, NA,NA))
```

Desired Output

```
 id value number_A
  1   NA        2
  1   NA        2
  1     A        2
  1     A        2
  2   NA        3
  2   NA        3
  2     A        3
  2     A        3
  2     B        3
  2     A        3
  3   NA         2
  3   NA         2
  3     B        2
  3     A        2
  3     B        2
  3     A        2
  4   NA         0
  4   NA         0
  4     B        0
  5   NA         0
  5   NA         0
  6   NA         0
  6   NA         0
```

I try it with the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(count =  row_number(value=="A"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904974/conditionally-count-in-dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(number_A = sum(value == "A", na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 23 x 3
      id value number_A
   <dbl> <chr>    <int>
 1     1 NA           2
 2     1 NA           2
 3     1 A            2
 4     1 A            2
 5     2 NA           3
 6     2 NA           3
 7     2 A            3
 8     2 A            3
 9     2 B            3
10     2 A            3
# ... with 13 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Base solution with the `aggregate` function.

```
df<- data.frame( id= c(1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 3, 3, 3,3 ,3,3,4,4,4, 5,5,6,6), value= c(NA, NA,"A", "A", NA,NA,"A","A","B","A",NA,NA,"B","A","B","A", NA, NA,"B",NA, NA, NA,NA))

# Calculate the number of A for each group id:
countA = aggregate(value ~ id, data=df, FUN=function(x){sum(x=="A", na.rm=TRUE))}, na.omit=na.pass)
countA
#   id value
# 1  1     2
# 2  2     3
# 3  3     2
# 4  4     0
# 5  5     0
# 6  6     0

# Set the value in countA to "countA" and merge with df
names(countA)[2] = "countA"
merge(df, countA, by="id")
#   id value countA
#1   1  <NA>      2
#2   1  <NA>      2
#3   1     A      2
#4   1     A      2
#5   2  <NA>      3
#6   2  <NA>      3
# ...
```

##### Explanation:

`aggregate` calculates a summary function for groups defined by `by` variable. Alternatively, this relationship can be provided with a formula.

The `function(x){sum(x=="A", na.rm=TRUE)}` simply calculates a sum of `A` values and removes the `NA`s that would otherwise bubble up.

Finally, by default, aggregate removes the values with `NA`s, which cause some groups to not be represented. This is fixed by the rule `na.omit=na.pass` which suppress this behaviour.

After that, we just rename a column in our aggregated result and `merge` the two `data.frames` by the `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
df %>% 
  add_count(id, wt = value=="A", name = "number_A")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also counts other values than `"A"` which wasn't intended by OP.

Comment: You are right, @MartinGal: I misread what the OP asked for...

Comment: I have just edited my solution taking into account your comment, @MartinGal. Thanks!